# Activity Indicator Stuck while Navigating in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I`m using xamarin forms 2.3.4.247 shared project. In my login page im navigating my page to another. while this page is rendering i`m showing a Activity Indicator in Main Page. But unfortunately Activity Indicator Stucks And After A couple of seconds the second page loads.i`ve tried these codes below and i got nothing.All of these codes are running into an async command.i`m testing my app in actual device on android platform.

1

```
activityIndicator.IsRunnig=true;
    new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
                        {
                            Navigation.PushAsync(new DeviceLoginView());
                        })).Start();
```

2

```
activityIndicator.IsRunnig=true;
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DeviceLoginView());
                });
```

3

```
 activityIndicator.IsRunnig=true;
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new DeviceLoginView());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Finally was able to make this issue right.
you can do all your asynchronous jobs in a Task.Run() method to run all of them in a new thread and NOT in the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

That issue is because your activity indicator is in the UI of the old page not on the new page, so when you do the Push the old page is not longer displaying. 
For have the result you want, you can use this plugin for keep having the loading during the transition 
https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs